# How to parse ints out of string in Haskell

Tags: string, parsing, haskell, character, point

I'm trying to parse strings of the format:

```
(x,y) (r,g,b)
```

My file contains this kind of string on each line.
I already extracted the lines, now i wanna extract its values, but i couldn't find something satisfying.
I wanted to do something like :

```
case str of
['(', x, ',', y, ')', ' ', '(', r, ',', g, ',', b, ')'] -> The rest
```

I know it doesn't work, I'm new to Haskell so i keep encountering errors i don't understand.
How can i make it ?

EDIT :
I have created this before, but i don't know how to really use it once the variable has been created :

```
data Points = Point Coords Colors
data Colors = Color Float Float Float
data Coords = Coord Int Int
```

Numbers are not limited to one digit, r, g and b range from 0 to 255.

Comment: You might want to read about parsers, particularly the `parsec` library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy hack for this particular task:

```
data Pix = Pix (Int,Int) (Int,Int,Int)
 deriving (Read, Show)

parsePix :: ReadS Pix
parsePix s = reads $ "Pix "++s
```

```
*Main> parsePix "(1,2) (3,4,5)"
[(Pix (1,2) (3,4,5),"")]
```

In general, you should look into proper parser-combinator libraries though, I recommend [megaparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec).

Comment: Thank you.
How can i return a pix instead of printing it and how do i read its values back once Pix created ?
EDIT : I'm not actually really getting it. Does this function create a Pix ? What is ReadS ?

Comment: [LMHTFY](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=ReadS). Basically, the result of `ReadS` is a list that either contains one valid parsed element, or nothing (if the parser failed).

Comment: So the first element of the returned value is a Pix ?

Comment: Yes. The other is just _the remaining part of the string_ (if any).

Comment: Then how can i get a single Pix, not in a list ? Or how do i extract it of the list ?

Comment: Like with any other list: by pattern-matching, `case ... of ((Pix pt color, _):_) -> ...`, or you can fold it, or `mapM_` over it, etc. etc..